# How do you use Snap's authentication mechanisms during a single POST request?

Tags: authentication, haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm working on a Haskell Snap-based web app, and I want to expose an API endpoint that will be invoked by a remote service without establishing an authenticated session a-priori; however, I do want that request to be authenticated, so the credentials should be provided at the time of the request.

You could imagine the request containing four fields:

- username
- password
- payload id
- payload file

The payload id and file might be irrelevant for this question, but I include them because I (a) need to support file uploads in this request (which, as I understand it, restricts the encoding used to send fields) and (b) need to retrieve at least one non-file field.  The combination of those things posed some difficulty when I set this up without authentication, so perhaps it is relevant.

In Snap parlance, let's call this handler `uploadHandler`.

As indicated above, I have this working fine without authentication, with a setup like this:

```
uploadHandler :: Handler App App ()
uploadHandler = do
  -- collect files / form fields and process as needed.

-- and using the routes:
routes :: [(ByteString, Handler App App ())]
routes = [ ("/login",    with auth handleLoginSubmit)
         , ("/logout",   with auth handleLogout)
         , ("/new_user", with auth handleNewUser)

         -- handle the upload:
         , ("/upload",   handleUpload)
         ]
```

The naive solution is to simply add 'with auth' and change the type of `handleUpload`:

```
uploadHandler :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
uploadHandler = do
  -- collect files / form fields and process as needed.

-- and using the routes:
routes :: [(ByteString, Handler App App ())]
routes = [ ("/login",    with auth handleLoginSubmit)
         , ("/logout",   with auth handleLogout)
         , ("/new_user", with auth handleNewUser)

         -- handle the upload, with auth:
         , ("/upload",   with auth handleUpload)
         ]
```

However, this seems to require two requests: (i) authenticate and establish a session, (ii) send the POST request containing the actual payload.

I found a way to do this in one request, but it seems like there should be a more elegant means.  Here's the example restricted POST handler I've hacked together:

```
restrictedPOST :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
restrictedPOST = do
  mName <- getPostParam "username"
  mPass <- getPostParam "password"
  let uName = C8.unpack $ fromMaybe "" mName
      pass = ClearText $ fromMaybe "" mPass

  authResult <- loginByUsername (T.pack uName) pass False
  case authResult of
    Left authFail -> writeText "Could not log in"
    Right user    -> writeText (T.append "Hello " (userLogin user))
```

Is there something like 'with auth' that I can use instead of turning this example (`restrictedPOST`) into a combinator?  I realize it may need to know which fields to get credentials out of, but I also know very little about web services (maybe there is another means? Maybe this is a total non-issue, and I just don't know how to check auth for POST requests. I'm open to any suggestions!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand what `with auth` is doing.  It has nothing to do with whether authentication is required.  All it does is convert a `Handler b (AuthManager b)` into a `Handler b v`.  No permissions checks are performed.  Your restrictedPOST function has the right idea.

Comment: I think you were right... I have a better understanding of what with auth does now.  Thanks!